# How to concat two videos and play it in flutter

Tags: flutter, video, concatenation

```
     var output =
          "${rootPath}_${DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch}_M3.mp4";
     String commandToExecute = '-i $latest -i $compress -filter_complex \'[0:0][1:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[out]\' -map \'[out]\' $output';

          await ffmpeg.execute(commandToExecute).then((rc) {
            if (rc == 0) {
              latest = output;
            }
          });
```

Tried this process but rc always shows 1 for android. how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried executeWithArguments approach? might do the trick

Comment: yes i did. but didnt work